# How to read user input from .aspx and store it in SQL Server database in .aspx.cs

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to programming in asp.net, I'm still learning and right now I'm building a login form.

This is my aspx (HTML file):

```
<div class="login">
    <input type="text" placeholder="User" name="user" id="user" runat="server"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" runat="server"><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-sucess" id="btn" runat="server" onserverclick="btn_Click">Login</button>
</div>
```

I need  to create a button click event in aspx.cs to store the data in SQL Server, in my registration form I did this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", user.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", password.Text);
```

The difference was that the TAG in the `.aspx` file for registration was like this:

```
<td class="auto-style8">  
    <asp:TextBox ID="nome" runat="server" Width="159px"></asp:TextBox>  
</td>
```

How can I do the same that I did in the registration form without using these asp tags?

Comment: If you're going to use Web Forms, why are you trying to avoid web controls?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get rid of ASP.NET tag controls which effectively are syntactic sugar around HTML equivalents. You could re-write you ASP Textbox tag as below:

```
<input type="text" ID="nome" runat="server" style="width:159px"></input>
```

The `runat="server"` attribute gives you the flexibility to access this control at code behind (aspx.cs) and if you do not intend to do that, it can be removed as well.

Comment: The way I understood @Pvxtotal question is he wants to eliminate the "ASP.NET" tags and this would the equivalent to what he has in the question

Comment: The problem is that without using asp tags, I can't use the .Text, is there another way?

Comment: you could access the `innerText` attribute at the server side as well. So you would do something like `nome..Attributes("innerText")`

Answer (score 0):

from code behind access the value of text control like this -

```
string userName = user.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly access value of controls by using name of that control

In your case

```
 <td class="auto-style8">  
        <asp:TextBox ID="nome" runat="server" Width="159px"></asp:TextBox>  
 </td>
```

you can access this value in .cs file like

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("user", nome.Text);
```